# Laravel 5: when persist form data, _token causes mass assignment exception

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5

When I try to persist form data, Laravel is throwing a mass assignment exception.

In the view I'm using `{!! form::open(...) !!}` which I know creates `_token` as a hidden field.

When the form data is sent to the controller, I'm using

```
$data = Input::all();
$order = Order::create($data);
$order->save();
```

Should I be adding a field for `_token` in my database? Or am I causing an error by doing something else wrong?

Comment: Don't use mass assignment, make a function that would take a $request object as a parameter and assign what is needed to the model. It will give you one place to list your fields as if it was $fillable property, but also (a) you can get more flexibility and (b) you can search up in your project all the function calls when needed. My problem when using mass assignment was a case when $fillable array should be different depending on user role. I wish I would not use mass assignment on the first place.

Comment: when you are calling `Order::create($data);` it saves, you don't have to `save()` it afterwards. And this is another reason for not using mass assignment. You can be in control of where you are saving the model.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A mass assignment exception is usually caused because you didn't specify the `fillable` (or `guarded` the opposite) attributes in your model. Do this:

```
class Order extends Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = ['field1', 'foo', 'bar'];
}
```

This way you also don't have to worry about `_token` because only the specified fields will be filled and saved in the db no matter what other stuff you pass to the model.

Comment: Is this OK? `Class Order extends Model { protected $table = 'orders'; protected $fillable = ['field1', 'foo', 'bar'];`

Comment: Yes. Well of course instead of `field1` etc you should specify your actual attributes. This is just an example.

Answer (score 7):

or

```
protected $guarded = array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are putting the $fillable or $guarded in the app\Order.php file and not the app\Http\Controllers\OrderController.php file.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your initial question.  You would want to do unset($request['_token']);  before your create.